# Is there a way to force SQL Server Network Configuration to recognize new IP addresses without full restart?

Tags: sql-server, ip

I added a new IP address to my server (Windows 2016). But I'm unable to see this new Ip address in SQL Server Network Configuration.
Restarting SQL services didn't solve anything. 
I guess rebooting the server would work, but is there any way around it?

Thanks

---

**UPDATE**

Sql server does not recognize new IPs in any way. I thought a reboot would solve that. I was wrong. I found the answer here: [https://mssqlwiki.com/tag/how-to-add-new-ip-to-sql-server/][1]
In short

1. You need to reinstall
2. You can edit register manually. Add new IPs here:  `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.X\MSSQLServer\SuperSocketNetLib\Tcp\IPn`

I chose the second way.

Comment: Does the new IP address show up in the OS? If restarting the SQL service didn't clear it up, my guess is "no".

Comment: The problem was uglier than a reboot. (see my edit)

Answer (score 3):

There is a third option instead of:

1. Reinstalling
2. Manually editing the registry

If you start the **SQL Server Installation center (64-Bit)** on your SQL Server, then you can select the option **Maintenance** in the left pane of the installation center and then click on **Repair** in the right-hand pane.

After supplying the path for the installation media, you can then continue to repair the **Shared components** and the **instance-specific** components of the SQL Server instance in question.

After you have completed these steps, reboot the server and the IP address will be available in the **SQL Server Configuration Manager**.

#### Answering Your Question

> Is there a way to force SQL Server Network Configuration to recognize new IP addresses without full restart?

No, you will have to perform any one of the three steps:

1. Repair

   - medium intrusive
   - permissions upheld in registry
   - not prone to errors
2. Registry Edit

   - least intrusive
   - permission not guaranteed
   - prone to typos/errors
3. Reinstall

   - clean slate